# Equivalent of a Vlookup in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge/join/vlookup data set two into dataset one by the unique_id.
Dataset two has many duplicates of the same unique_id and information associated with it. Only one column from dataset two is important the amount_due. I would like to add the amount_due column into dataset one by the correct unique_id, dataset two below.

Data Set One

```
    unique_id  df1  df2  df3     df4
    1234       1    h    8/4/18  no
    2341       2    nl   8/5/18  yes
    3412       3    sg   8/3/18  no
    4213       4    hi   7/3/18  yes
```

Data Set Two

```
    unique_id  df1  df2  df3     df4  amount_due  df5
    1234       1    h    8/4/18  no   $100        mcd
    1234       1    h    8/4/18  no   $100        mcd
    1234       1    h    8/4/18  no   $100        mcd
    2341       2    nl   8/5/18  yes  $1          hsn
    3412       3    sg   8/3/18  no   $200        bcbs
    3412       3    sg   8/3/18  no   $200        bcbs
    4213       4    hi   7/3/18  yes  $2.22       r
    4213       4    hi   7/3/18  yes  $2.22       r
```

Desired output below

```
    unique_id  df1  df2  df3     df4  amount_due
    1234       1    h    8/4/18  no   $100
    2341       2    nl   8/5/18  yes  $1
    3412       3    sg   8/3/18  no   $200
    4213       4    hi   7/3/18  yes  $2.22
```

Comment: Does this even require a vlookup? Data Set 1 is contained within Data Set 2. Your desired output is just Data Set 2 with unique rows and without the last column.  Data Set 1 is superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr`, we can `select` only the rows we're interested in in `df2`, then filter it to contain only `distinct` rows before `join`ing it (left or right doesn't matter here) to `df1.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
    select(unique_id, amount_due) %>%
    distinct() %>%
    right_join(df1, by = 'unique_id')

  unique_id amount_due df1 df2    df3 df4
1      1234       $100   1   h 8/4/18  no
2      2341         $1   2  nl 8/5/18 yes
3      3412       $200   3  sg 8/3/18  no
4      4213      $2.22   4  hi 7/3/18 yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Using R base

```
> merge(df1, unique(df2)[, c("unique_id", "amount_due")], by="unique_id")
  unique_id df1 df2    df3 df4 amount_due
1      1234   1   h 8/4/18  no       $100
2      2341   2  nl 8/5/18 yes         $1
3      3412   3  sg 8/3/18  no       $200
4      4213   4  hi 7/3/18 yes      $2.22
```